# Reuse XML fragment of a bean

Tags: java, spring

I have an xml file that works for what I am needing to do, but it has a lot of code that is duplicated. For example - username and password is part of every bean in the xml file. I created the below file with a `parentBean` id hoping I could reuse everything in there in the child beans. But I am getting `The content of element type "bean" must match` error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
   <bean id="parentBean" class="com.dataloader.ProcessRunner" abstract="true">
   <description>Parent bean.</description>
      <map>
         <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true" />
         <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\DLTest\accountExportSoapTrace.log" />
         <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.com" />
         <entry key="sfdc.username" value="test" />
         <entry key="sfdc.password" value="5b69d70a1dd974a21ecf64595ac02596f0c7c" />
         <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="D:\SF\dataLoader.key" />
         <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600" />
      </map>
   </bean>
   <bean id="account" singleton="false" parent="parentBean">
      <description>accountInsert exports all fields from the Account object.</description>
      <property name="name" value="account" />
      <property name="configOverrideMap">
         <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account" />
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract" />
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT ID, Name, Phone FROM Account" />
            <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="D:\SF\accountExport.sdl" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="D:\SF\Account.csv" />
            <!--entry key="process.outputSuccess" 
                    value="c:\DLTest\accountExport_success.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.outputError" 
                    value="c:\DLTest\Log\accountExport_error.csv"/-->
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite" />
            <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2018-10-1T00:00:00.000-0800" />
         </map>
      </property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="contact" singleton="false" parent="parentBean">
      <description>contactExport exports all fields from the Contact object.</description>
      <property name="name" value="contact" />
      <property name="configOverrideMap">
         <map>
            <!--entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/-->
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Contact" />
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract" />
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact" />
            <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="D:\SF\contactExport.sdl" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="D:\SF\Contacts.csv" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite" />
            <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2018-10-1T00:00:00.000-0800" />
         </map>
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the property name on you parent bean.
To merge the maps from the parent and child beans, set attribute `default-merge="true"` on the beans element.

i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
    default-merge="true">
   <bean id="parentBean" class="com.dataloader.ProcessRunner" abstract="true">
   <description>Parent bean.</description>
     <property name="configOverrideMap">
       <map>
         <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true" />
         <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\DLTest\accountExportSoapTrace.log" />
         <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.com" />
         <entry key="sfdc.username" value="test" />
         <entry key="sfdc.password" value="5b69d70a1dd974a21ecf64595ac02596f0c7c" />
         <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="D:\SF\dataLoader.key" />
         <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600" />
       </map>
     </property>
   </bean>
   ... rest of the applicationContext
```

Comment: Thank you, @pcoates for the feedback. Now I am getting a `Attribute "default-merge" must be declared for element type "beans"` error.

Comment: @Aaron it's probably down to how you've got the doctype defined. I've updated my answer to show how the schema and namespace details are usually declared. I'm not familiar with using DOCTYPE and DTD.

Comment: It looks like the dtd hasn't ben updated since 2006 http://www.springframework.org/dtd/ , so you're better off using the xsd unless you have a good reason not to. spring-beans-2.0.dtd is newer than spring-beans.dtd so you could just change to 2.0.